# custom model relations

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

how to set custom or override default model relations configurations such as foreign key, and primary key field in codeigniter DataMapper? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. [See the rules in the manual.](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/database.html)

Comment: I can't find how to set fields naming without rule. I have some tables that doesn't use fields naming rules for primary key and foreign key, is it possible to set custom field name for foreign key? 
thanks

Comment: No, it's not possible. You **have to** follow the naming rules for fields if you want to be able to use DataMapper effectively. As the link I provided you said, "[the table and field naming rules] are the foundation of DataMapper's ORM methods."

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer. Too bad to hear DM's settings is not overridable.